# Accessing ExactTarget A/B test data via REST API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm hoping to access the A/B testing groups from ExactTarget via the [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm), but can't see any way to do this in the API docs. Are the A/B test groups just not exposed via the API? Or are they grouped under another endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

A/B Testing functionality is not something that currently exists/is accessible through the REST API or SOAP API and there are not currently plans to enrich this feature as is to expand our APIs to support it.

Journey Builder Path Optimizer would be something that you could use to achieve very similar functionality to A/B testing and have even greater ability to customize within it.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_may_2020_journey_path_optimizer.htm&type=5